# Simulation of Markov chain slower than in Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, performance, matlab

I run the same test code in Python+Numpy and in Matlab and see that the Matlab code is faster by an order of magnitude. I want to know what is the bottleneck of the Python code and how to speed it up.

I run the following test code using Python+Numpy (the last part is the performance sensitive one):

```py
# Packages
import numpy as np
import time

# Number of possible outcomes
num_outcomes = 20
# Dimension of the system
dim = 50
# Number of iterations
num_iterations = int(1e7)

# Possible outcomes
outcomes = np.arange(num_outcomes)
# Possible transition matrices
matrices = [np.random.rand(dim, dim) for k in outcomes]
matrices = [mat/np.sum(mat, axis=0) for mat in matrices]
# Initial state
state = np.random.rand(dim)
state = state/np.sum(state)

# List of samples
samples = np.random.choice(outcomes, size=(num_iterations,))
samples = samples.tolist()


# === PERFORMANCE-SENSITIVE PART OF THE CODE ===

# Update the state over all iterations
start_time = time.time()
for k in range(num_iterations):
    sample = samples[k]
    matrix = matrices[sample]
    state = np.matmul(matrix, state)
end_time = time.time()

# Print the execution time
print(end_time - start_time)
```

I then run an equivalent code using Matlab (the last part is the performance sensitive one):

```matlab
% Number of possible outcomes
num_outcomes = 20;
% Number of dimensions
dim = 50;
% Number of iterations
num_iterations = 1e7;

% Possible outcomes
outcomes = 1:num_outcomes;
% Possible transition matrices
matrices = rand(num_outcomes, dim, dim);
matrices = matrices./sum(matrices,2);
matrices = num2cell(matrices,[2,3]);
matrices = cellfun(@shiftdim, matrices, 'UniformOutput', false);
% Initial state
state = rand(dim,1);
state = state./sum(state);

% List of samples
samples = datasample(outcomes, num_iterations);


% === PERFORMANCE-SENSITIVE PART OF THE CODE ===

% Update the state over all iterations
tic;
for k = 1:num_iterations
    sample = samples(k);
    matrix = matrices{sample};
    state = matrix * state;
end
toc;
```

The Python code is consistently slower than the Matlab code by an order of magnitude, and I am not sure why.

Any idea where to start?

I run the Python code with the Python 3.10 interpreter and Numpy 1.22.4. I run the Matlab code with Matlab R2022a. Both codes are run on Windows 11 Pro 64 bits on a Lenovo T14 ThinkPad with the following processors:

11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

EDIT 1: I made some additional tests and it looks like the culprit is some type of Python-specific constant overhead at low matrix sizes:

[image]

As hpaulj and MSS suggest, this might mean that a JIT compiler could solve some of these issues. I will do my best to try this in the near future.

EDIT 2: I ran the code under Pypy 3.9-v7.3.11-win64 and although it does change the scaling and even beats Cpython at small matrix sizes, it generally incurs a big overhead for this particular code:

[image]

So a JIT compiler could help if there are ways to mitigate this overhead. Otherwise a Cython implementation is probably the remaining way to go...

Comment: looks like you're basically asking why the (proprietary-for-a-reason) **Mat**rix **lab**oritory is faster than Python for repeatedly doing **matrix** operations?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not an answer to the question. I know Matlab very well. But that's not the question. The question is: why is it slower and is there anything I can do to improve the Python code.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, that's why I left it as a comment instead. MATLAB is _very_ good at matrix operations by design, there are lots of near-duplicate questions on this site asking a similar thing

Comment: Fine, I get that. Then just say that, maybe refer me to such a duplicate question, and please sound less condescending (re-read your comment and imagine you're the one getting it). That will go down much better for everyone. No hard feelings.

Comment: Anyways, I just noticed that for larger matrix dimensions and fewer matrices to choose from (num_outcomes=2 and dim=1000), the Matlab code actually becomes *worse*... So I'm not sure it's the matrix multiplication that is the problem. It might have to do with some allocation overhead or memory. I'm not sure.

Comment: The first comment wasn't rhetorical, which I think makes it seem less condescending. I was seeking confirmation whether that's fundamentally what you're asking, because without being able to run the Python code that's the impression your example gives. And if that's the case, I was also highlighting that MATLAB is generally just designed to be fundamentally quick at matrix arithmetic. There are [lots of related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%5Bmatlab%5D+slower), sometimes it's to do with column order or memory allocation, sometimes it's just the matrix operations

Comment: make sure it is fair comparison, for example a) data types are the same (float64?) b) both Matlab and Numpy use multiprocessing (or not)

Comment: Often the difference is that MATLAB does a jit compilation, especially of loops.  I'm not sure if that's the case here.  The only obvious loop is that repeated `state = np.matmul(matrix, state)`.  `matmul` is pretty fast, at least for numeric arrays.  But doing it many times adds up.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to set up PyPy and see if that makes a difference for low matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, the main hindrance is `np.matmul(matrix,state)`.

If we unroll the loop:

```
st[1] = m[0]@st[0]
st[2] = m[1]@st[1] = m[1]@m[0]@st[0]
st[3] = m[2]@m[1]@m[0]@st[0]
```

There is  no obvious vectorized way to do looped `np.matmul` in a non loopy way.

A better way would be to do it in log_2(n) loops.

```
import numpy as np
outcomes = 20
dim = 50
num_iter = int(1e7)

mat = np.random.rand(outcomes,dim, dim)
mat = mat/mat.sum(axis=1)[...,None]
state = np.random.rand(dim)
state = state/np.sum(state)

samples = np.random.choice(np.arange(outcomes), size=(num_iter,))


a = mat[samples,...]
# This while loop takes log_2(num_iter) iterations
while len(a) > 1:
    a = np.matmul(a[::2, ...], a[1::2, ...])

state = np.matmul(a,state)
```

The time may be further reduced by using numba jit.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to vectorize unfortunately. The log decimation is a good idea, but this could be implemented in matlab too. I guess the JIT compiler is the most sensible way forward. See the addendum to my original post for evidence. I'll accept the answer as I think it covers the possible issues.

Comment: My pleasure my answer could help you.